# If n is an odd integer, show there exists a positive integer k such that 2^k mod n = 1.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Hi I've been trying to solve this problem for at least 4 hours now but I can't figure it out. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it!

I am asked to prove this using the **pigeonhole principle**:

"If n is an odd integer, show there exists a positive integer k such that 2^k mod n = 1."

I know that n has n possible remainders (0,1,2,...,n-1) and that this may be the "pigeonholes". I also found that as you increase k in 2^k and calculate 2^k mod n, the remainders occur in a pattern... (Like for 2^k mod 5, when k=0 -> remainder is 2, k=1 -> r=4, k=2 -> r=3, k=3 -> r=1, then the pattern repeats 2,4,3,1.)

Also, I found n divides 2^k - 1, so 2^k - 1 = nb, for an integer b. Since 2^k is even and n is odd, b must be odd too...

(Thank you to both who helped me!!! I am really grateful :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose that there are two integers $m$ and $m+k$ such that
$$
2^{m} = 2^{m+k} = 2^m \cdot 2^k \pmod{n}
$$
What can we say about $2^k$?

---

**Solution:**
I've tried to use your notation to make this more comprehensible. Let me know if anything is unclear.

We look at the first $n+1$ values of $\left(2^k \mod n\right)$.  We note by the pigeon-hole principle that since there are $n$ possible values modulo $n$, at least two of these have to be the same.  So, there are some integers $p>q$ for which
$$
2^p \mod n = 2^q \mod n
$$
Which I denote by
$$
2^p \equiv 2^q \pmod n
$$
We also note that
$$
2^{p-q}\cdot 2^q \equiv 2^{(p-q) + q} \equiv 2^{p} \pmod n
$$
So that we now have
$$
2^{p-q}\cdot 2^q  \equiv 2^q \pmod n
$$
By the Euclidean algorithm and since $2^{q}$ is relatively prime to $n$, we can find an $x$ and $y$ such that $x2^{q} + ny = 1 \implies x2^{q} = 1 - ny$.  As a consequence, we conclude that $x \cdot 2^{q} \pmod n = 1$.  We now multiply both sides of the above equivalence to get
$$
2^{p-q}\cdot \left(2^q\cdot x\right)  \equiv 2^q \cdot x \pmod n \implies\\
2^{p-q}\cdot 1  \equiv 1 \pmod n \implies\\
2^{p-q} \equiv 1 \pmod n
$$
So, we have $2^{p-q} \mod n = 1$ as desired.

Comment: 2^k gives a different remainder than 2^(k+1)? Or since k cannot be greater than n-1 (1 less than n since 0 is not a possible remainder), k is either 1,2,3,...,or n-1...

Comment: I haven't applied the pigeon-hole principle yet.  Start with $$2^m = 2^m \cdot 2^k \pmod n$$ and "divide on both sides" by $2^m$.

Comment: 2^(k-m) = 1, k-m = 0, so k=m?

Comment: No, we simply have $2^k = 1 \pmod n$, and that's what we wanted.  Using the pigeon-hole principle, you can now guarantee that such an $m$ and $k$ exist.

Comment: So 2^k mod n = 1... and by the pigeonhole principle, because... there are n-1 possible k and m... I still need a little more help please!...

Comment: There are at most $n$ possible values for $2^k \pmod n$.  Let's look at $2^1,2^2,\dots,2^{n+1}$.  Why can we guarantee that two of these are the same?

Comment: You named n+1 values, so ceil((n+1)/n) = 2. How can we prove that a 1 will be one of the values though? Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: All you need is that $2^p = 2^q \pmod n$ for some $p>q$.  From there, you can conclude that $1 = 2^{p-q}$, so that $2^{p-q}$ is the power of $2$ that you're looking for.

Comment: And just to clarify... I am trying to prove 2^k mod n = 1, not 2^k = (congruent modulo) 1 (modn). *Edit - Oh wait, that's the same thing haha, nvm.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why gcd(2^q,n)=1 lets you divide both sides of 2^p = 2^q (mod n) by 2^q?

Comment: There must be some integers $x,y$ such that $$x\cdot 2^q + y \cdot n = \operatorname{gcd}(2^q,n) = 1$$ That is, we have $$x \cdot 2^q = 1 \pmod n$$ So, we can "divide" both sides by $2^q$ by multiplying by $x$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit clearer. If you multiply by x though, wouldn't you get x^2 * 2^q = x (mod n)?

Comment: No, you have $$x \cdot 2^q = x \cdot 2^q \cdot 2^{p-q} \implies 1 = 2^{p-q}$$

Comment: Could you please explain that a little more? All of these explanations are rather vague to me and they're not in my textbook or were taught in class. I've also searched google and several combinatorics textbooks before. I am pretty desperate. If you could give me a dumbed down explanation I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: All right, I'll edit my answer and put something that hopefully helps.  Have you heard of the Euclidean algorithm or reverse Euclidean algorithm by any chance?

Comment: Thanks so much. We've done one Euclidean algorithm problem where we also did some reverse operations to find solutions of a and b for ax + by = gcd(x,y), so I think I get the gist of it.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I think I almost get it completely now. I just can't understand how you can change 2^p to 2^q using the Euclidean algorithm. So close...

Comment: Gah! Sorry, that was a typo.  See now.

Comment: Oh haha that's okay but I meant the equations following "We also note that..." and "So that we now have..."

Comment: How about now?$\,\,$

Comment: Sorry my internet suddenly failed me so I had to get on my phone. I just wanted to say yess, thank you! I get it now!! Finally after all these days :D you are awesome!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not, in that case there are two integers $p>q\in{0... n-1}$ such that $2^{p}= 2^{q} \ Mod(n)$. Since $gcd(2^{q},n)=1$ Hence you can divide both sides by $2^q$ to obtain

$2^{p-q}= 1 \ Mod(n)$

---

Comment: How does the gcd(2^q,n) matter here?

Comment: The guy above there is wrong. Assumption 2^p = 2^q mod n is totally wrong. Suppose n is 29, how can we get 2^q for p > q ? Impossible.

Comment: Precisely. If not, then $2^{p}$ from $p=0...n-1$ will assume all the values from $0..n-1$ include 1, thus there will be a $p$ s.t. $2^p=1$ mod n